# How can I get nested objects, which have not empty values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, reduce

I have write this function

```
export const func = (object) => {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).filter(([, {
        url,
        value
    }]) => {
        return (url && url !== '') || (value && value !== '');
    }).map(([key, { url, value }]) => {
        return [key, url ? url : value];
    }));
};
```

its return Object with key value pair

```
{
  exampleKey: "someNotEmptyUrl"
}
```

but i want it to return this type of object

```
{
  action: exampleKey
  url: "someNotEmptyUrl"
}
```

maybe i used to be write reduce instead of map ?

Comment: What does your input object look like? Can you add a sample to your question?

Comment: this is example object 

`{ "action1": {"url": ""}, "action2": {"url": ""},"action3": {"url": ""},"action4{"url":"notEmpty"},"action5": {"value": ""}}`

and output is  `{"action4": "notEmpty"}`

Comment: i want output look like this `{action: action4, url: "notEmpty"}`

Comment: What is your expected output if `action5` also had `{"value": "also not empty"}`, in addition to `action4` still having url set?

Comment: in this only one has a not empty value or url

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `Object.entries` and then spread operator to build a new object:

```js
const func = (object) => {
    let [action,v] = Object.entries(object).find(([k,v]) => !!v.url);
    return ({ action, ...v });
};

const obj = { "action1": {"url": ""}, "action2": {"url": ""}, "action3": {"url": ""}, "action4": {"url": "notEmpty"}, "action5": {"value": ""} };

console.log(func(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have more than one object with a non-empty URL value create a new array and `push` new objects into it.

```js
const obj={action1:{url:""},action2:{url:"notEmpty2"},action3:{url:""},action4:{url:"notEmpty4"}};

const arr = [];

for (const [action, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  const { url } = value;
  if (url) arr.push({ action, url });
}

console.log(arr);
```